# from xib to storyboard UIButton or no?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I created an xib file(which is a gridView) outside of storyboard.  If you create a button on the xib file and wanted to move from that button back to the storyboard and passing GridViewItems. How do you do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. First, you set a push segue on the storyboard from the view you called the grid view to the view you want to go. Of course, you have to connect your button in the grid view xib file to IBOutlet property.

Then add this to the tableView

```
[cellview.button addTarget:self action:@selector(toNextView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and create a function toNextView and perform the segue in the function:

```
[self.own performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OwnViewToNewView" sender:item];
```